# Running Javascript through AutoHotkey?

Tags: javascript, windows, autohotkey, photoshop-script

I have this idea, taking Photoshop events recorded   and converted to Javascript code using Adobe's script listener and then triggering this Javascript code using Autohotkey.

For example, recording an action that will trigger free transform
in Photoshop and then triggering it via Autohotkey.

```
   a:: 
    Run, SomeJavaScript.jsx, C:\Users\Me\Documents\Adobe Scripts\
    return
```

I think this will prove to be slow. as it is accesing a file on a HDD.
Is there a way to have the .JS code to be "live" so that it is always ready to be executed by Autohotkey ?

I am new to Javascript within the context of Photoshop,
so I am just looking to be pointed in the right direction to learn more.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you might want to look at the Script Events Manager in the File > Scripts menu.  I use this to set some scripts to launch when Photoshop opens, but there are other events and even custom events you can set.

Comment: Have you tried to run the file though? I run a lot of scripts almost the same way and they execute almost instantly

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back to me. No I have not tried running it this way. This is all new to me and so I am just arming myself with some knowledge. But I will get start this weekend and see how it goes.