# Run adobe Java scripts for primer outside Extended script (AHK or command Line)

Tags: javascript, cmd, autohotkey, adobe-premiere

I wanted to run a java script for adobe primer pro in auto hot key that should add clips to the time line once executed.

My adobe script looks like this:

```
#target premierepro

main();

var VASequenece =app.project.activeSequence ;

var project = app.project;

var videoTracks   = app.project.activeSequence.videoTracks;

var rootProject = project.rootItem;

function main(){
//codes to be executed here!
}
```

From what I have read in here [Running Javascript through AutoHotkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62824696/running-javascript-through-autohotkey)
 is that you can run the code directly using this script

```
Run, C:\Users\User\Documents\Adobe Scripts\test1111.jsx
return
```

The issue that I have right now is when I run the auto hot key script nothing happens!

I googled more to see how far I could get and I saw some people used CMD like here [how-to-run-js-in-estk-with-command-line](http://jfli04.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-run-js-in-estk-with-command-line.html) to run the scripts and when I tested it out also did nothing!

please help as I don't know what I did wrong!

Another link that I was following was [Premiere Pro Script execution without ExtendScript Toolkit confirmation](https://community.adobe.com/t5/premiere-pro/premiere-pro-script-execution-without-extendscript-toolkit-confirmation/m-p/6855432) ... In which one of them said I have to add an empty txt file called

```
extendscriptprqe.txt
```

Still nothing happens!

Comment: Your path has a space, wrap it around quotes and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: I'm sorry... that didn't work .
ok what happens simply is that the program (ahk) just gives me (exit code:0 )

Comment: The file exist ... I mean if I gave the program a file that doesn't exist it will give me an error.

Comment: I don't see anything happening in Primere pro . as the code is supposed to add clips in the time line. When I execute the code in ESTK the clips gets added ... but when I run it in ahk or cmd nothing happens!

Comment: what do you mean by Auto run ? and how to auto run a script ?

Comment: @KJ  people can execute ESKT script in auto hot key for adobe photoshop so why can't I do the same thing for adobe primer ?